# How do you have a parented object stay in one place while the parent moves

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

I am trying to make it look like a sword is being pushed into the ground but i don't know how to keep the sword in the ground while the parent moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use a "child of" constraint for that.

[image]

You can keyframe the influence (should be 1 until the sword is pushed in the ground) and 0 one frame after that.

you can keyframe the objects position + rotation at the last frame with influence 1 and at the frame + 1 after that.

result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is parenting it obligatory?

There's an alternate option of parenting which is the constraint: child of. You can turn off location to make it so you can move the parent without moving the child, or use keyframes to turn off it's infuence.

You can also use the limit location constraint, by using the minimum and maximum coordinates as the coordinate of where you want it  to be, to lock it into place regardless of the parent.